# Regarding iterated maps $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, and strictly decreasing norm

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Consider a map $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, and the iteration $(x,y) \mapsto g(x,y)$. Say that the origin is an asymptotically stable fixed point and there is a region $A$ in the first quadrant where we can show that for all $(x_0,y_0) \in A$,

1. $g(x,y) \in A$
2. $\|g(x,y)\| < \|(x,y)\|$
3. $g(x,y)$ continuous

Now, my goal is to show that all $(x,y) \in A$ will eventually converge to the origin, or equivalently $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \|g^k(x,y)\| = 0.$$

I initially thought that the conditions listed above were sufficient, but now I have doubts. What if, even though the norm was strictly decreasing, it only approached some nonzero limit, with $$\lim_{k \to \infty} g^k(x,y) = p \ne (0,0) \in A.$$

My question is: could such a $p$ exist? For it cannot be a fixed point under the iteration due to (2) above. This means that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} g^k(p) \ne p$$

Basically I am pretty sure there is a contradiction in combining $$\lim_{k \to \infty} g^k(x,y) = p$$ with $$g(p) \ne p,$$ but I can't exactly pin it down.

Summed up, is it possible that there could be some sequence $\{(x,y),g(x,y), g^2(x,y), \ldots g^k(x,y)\}$ that never reaches the origin, even though there are no fixed points in $A$ besides the origin? And why not precisely? Thank you.

Comment: Is $g$ continuous?

Comment: Within A at least, yes. I'll add this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is not continuous, then there is such a sequence, even in 1D, take for example 
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}1/4+x/2 & \mbox{ for } x > 1/2\\ 0 & \mbox{ else}\end{cases}$$

However if $g$ needs to be continous then there is no such function. Assume there is a sequence of points $p_k = g^k(x_0,y_0)$ not converging to 0.

Since $g$ and the norm are continuous, $f:(x,y) \mapsto \|g(x,y)\|$ is a continous function. But clearly $f(p_k)$ is a decreasing sequence and bounded from below, so $f(p_k)$ converges to some $r > 0$.

Since $\|p_k\| < \|p_0\|$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $p_k$ is a bounded sequence, so by Bolzano-Weierstrass, there is some converging subsequence $p_{k_l} \rightarrow p \neq 0$. Now on one hand by continuity of $f$

$$ r= \lim_{l\rightarrow \infty} f(p_{k_l}) = f(p) = \|g(p)\|$$

and on the other hand

$$ r = \lim_{l\rightarrow \infty} f(p_{k_l-1}) = \lim_{l\rightarrow \infty} \|g(p_{k_l-1})\| = \lim_{l\rightarrow \infty} \|p_{k_l}\| = \|p\|$$

and thus $\|p\|=r=\|g(p)\|$ which is a contradiction.

Edit: also I just noted, I need that A is closed, otherwise $p$ may not lie in $A$ and there probably again is a counterexample.

Comment: I haven't quite followed this argument. Could you expand on the sentence beginning with "Furthermore due to boundedness..." ? I don't immediately see why we know that both of those sequences converge to r. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited it a bit, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I should point out that A doesn't necessarily have to be closed, it just has to contain those limit points that can be reached by iteration. I'm not sure of the terminology here, but for example if A was the quarter unit disk in the first quadrant, it needn't include the quarter circle, but it would have to have to include the line segments along the axes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample. Let the region $A$ be
$$\{(x,y) \, | \, x > 0, y > 0, xy > 1\}
$$
Let $\overline A$ be the closure of $A$:
$$\{(x,y) \, | \, x>0, y>0 ,xy\ge 1\}
$$
Define the map restricted to $\overline A$ as follows: on each ray $R$ through the origin in the first quadrant, map the subray $R \cap \overline A$ to itself by linearly shrinking $R \cap \overline A$ towards its base point on the hyperbola $xy=1$. Note that iteration of a point of $A$ converges to a point on the hyperbola. You can choose the linear shrinking factors on different rays to be equal, so that this produces a continuous map on $\overline A$.

Meanwhile, take a tiny closed ball $B$ around the origin and let the map restrict on $B$ to scalar multipliciation by a factor of $1/2$, so that origin is an "asymptotically stable fixed point".

Finally, extend continuously to all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Interesting! I am trying to reconcile this with mlk's answer. What if I further say that A must contain the origin?

Comment: That might make a difference. Also, in my example, $A$ is not closed.

Comment: If you extend $g$ by continuity to the whole plane, all the points on the hyperbola will be fixed, and the condition $\|g(x,y)\|<\|(x,y)\|$ will not hold.

Comment: Julian, that is what I was thinking, but I only stated that that condition hold on $A$.

Comment: Indeed. The hyperbola itself is disjoint from $A$.

Comment: I'm going to select the other answer just because it has ended up being more helpful for my problem, BUT this answer was a very good counter example for why A must be closed!